# How to redirect to other way on a select onChange event?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to make a product browser selection interface that when I click the selection of productType in the `column1`, the `column2` will appear the product with the selected productType by fetching information in the database (`SELECT productName from products WHERE productTYPE = 1`).

I've done it with ajax, but it turns out ajax is not permitted in this assignment(really sad!)

I can't come up with the solution without ajax. So Is there any way to make a post/get request with parameter and redirect to the self page(with self-post technique), only after I select a productType in the column1(onChange event on select element)

[image]

Comment: @PLB I have little knowledge about it, is this same as iframe? and Have frame deprecate or not?

Comment: Yes, they are deprecated but they still work fine. When I was suggesting frames I was talking about iframes (inline frames). By the way, even facebook uses iframes to load data from third-party pages.

Comment: @PLB good to know that, I'm gonna try it thanks

Answer (score 2):

What if you just outputted all the Products in a single select when you load the page and hide all the options by default then you can unhide the correct ones when you select a Product Line from column1.

A second option is to put multiple selects on the page when load, one for each Product Line and then hide all those selects by default and show/hide them as the appropriate column1 is selected.

Comment: +1 for the show and hide technique, I'm going to try this out