# How to share data between php and javascript in DOM?

Tags: php, javascript, dom

If you read [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12039528/456218), you may know that the way of sharing data between php and javascript DOM is not permitted in this assignment:

```
+-----------+   +------------+  +----------| +----------+  +-----------+    
|javascript +---+Ajax Request+--+handle.php+-+result.xml+->+DOM parser |    
+-----------+   +------------+  +----------+ +----------+  +-----------+
```

so I'm thinking about get all the information in the mysql all at once as an array, and try to  access this array by javascript without ajax request.

The only way that I can come up with is

```
   +---------+     +-----------------------------+  +--------------------------------------+
   |Php array|     | write in Dom make it hidden |  | Parse the hidden element by DOM API  |
   +---------+     +-----------------------------+  +--------------------------------------+
```

But this doesn't seems elegant at all, Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why not pass the mysql data to the DOM as a json object initially?

Comment: @PeterKirby That's the answer I'm looking for, But I'm a noobie about this, I don't know how to do this? How can I use php to generate JSON and available in javascript

Comment: Why are we doing your homework? I hope this isn't college... paying thousands of dollars to take classes, then not doing the work to learn the material would be a huge waste (when learning programming, figuring out how to do it is how you learn!). It's also a fraud perpetrated on everyone who sees a college on your resume. If this is homework, you're a bad person.

Comment: @DanGrossman sorry for this. I should work hard to because a better learner

Comment: `But this doesn't seems elegant at all, Is there a better way to do this?` This is not "not elegant" - it's actually pretty common way to do what you want :) We, for example, generate js files with data. That's how manufacturer-model dropdowns work here http://auto.drom.ru/addbull/ (That page is in Russian, go for first 2 dropdown from the top of the page). Js file itsef is `firms_models.js` (we wanted it to be cached by user's browser and benifit from not performing ajax and SQL queries)

Answer (score 2):

Query the database, and print the results as JavaScript inside a script tag. Now all the data is sitting in local JavaScript variables that you can use however you want.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  products = [];

  <?php
  mysql_connect('host', 'username', 'password');
  mysql_select_db('dbname');    

  $sql = "SELECT productName from products WHERE productTYPE = 1";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "products.push('" . addslashes($row['productName']) . "'); \n";

  }

  ?>

  //do something with all the stuff in the products array
  alert("There are " + products.length + " products in the array.");

</script>
```

Comment: Great! How could I not think of this solution, but in this case, I can't use external javascript, but only inline javascript to let php do the job

Comment: There is no external javascript here. This is the same document you'll write all your other javascript in. You can't get data from PHP without either printing it in the HTTP response (this), or issuing another request (AJAX). If your teacher wants you to populate that second list based on the first, without AJAX, this is what he/she is looking for.

Comment: Yes, I'm try to implement it. BTW Could I leverage the usage of json, I mean let php generate JSON and javascript get it as an object

Comment: Yes, you can. It involves changing only two lines of the PHP code above. I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: I'd go with building a JSON object - could be more compact, e.g. `var products = <?=json_encode($products)?>;`